# Populating google maps with different locations based on results from mysql database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I am setting up hotel listing to appear on google maps.
this is the result from ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/hotel/welcome/get_map_listings',
            data: {category:category},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery.each(data, function(index, item) {

                });

            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("some error");
            }
        });
```

this are the results:

```
[{"id":"1","hotelname":"The Noble Hotel","hotellongitude":"35.29894349999995","hotellatitude":"0.5113938999999998"},{"id":"2","hotelname":"Sirikwa Hotel","hotellongitude":"35.275458399999934","hotellatitude":"0.5207466999999999"},{"id":"3","hotelname":"Nakubreeze Hotel","hotellongitude":"","hotellatitude":""}]
```

this is map function:

```
function locationData(locationURL, locationImg, locationTitle, locationAddress, locationPrice) {
            return ('<div class="map-popup-wrap"><div class="map-popup"><div class="infoBox-close"><i class="far fa-times"></i></div><a href="' + locationURL + '" class="listing-img-content fl-wrap"></a> <div class="listing-content fl-wrap"><div class="listing-title fl-wrap"><h4><a href=' + locationURL + '>' + locationTitle + '</a></h4></div></div></div></div>')
        }
```

and locations variable from sample manually inputted dummy data:

```
var locations = [
            [locationData('welcome/hotel/2', 'Sample Hotel'), 40.72956781, -73.99726866, 0, markerIcon],
        ];
```

I am really not sure of how to place these array values so that it gets displayed on the map

Comment: actually your link has completely different content

Comment: Please try this one: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/importing_data